# How to fix error "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" when running "sc = SparkContext()"?

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I installed PySpark on Amazon AWS using instructions:
https://medium.com/@josemarcialportilla/getting-spark-python-and-jupyter-notebook-running-on-amazon-ec2-dec599e1c297

This works fine:

```py
Import pyspark as SparkContext
```

This gives error:

```
sc = SparkContext()

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-2dfc28fca47d> in <module>
    ----> 1 sc = SparkContext()

    TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyspark` is a module. You import `SparkContext` from `pyspark`.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
```

Spark 2.0 has SparkSession as single entry point. You don't need SparkConf, SparkContext or SQLContext separetly as they’re encapsulated within the SparkSession.

For more details please refer [pyspark.sql.SparkSession](http://%20https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession) documentaion.